# PYTHON - Keywords Input List

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

I have it set so if 'yea' is in the input it outputs a certain responsonce but I want it to understand yea,yes and yeah. Here is the code!

```
name = raw_input ("What's your name?")

if 'Sean' in name:    
name1 = raw_input("Downey or Paul?")        
if 'Downey' in name1:    
    print ("Hi Sean Downey")
    x = raw_input("Did you know that the name is irish?")
    if x == 'yea':
        print ('oh cool')
elif 'Paul' in name1:    
    print ("Hi Sean Paul")    
else:    
    print ("I don't know that Sean")
else:    
print ('Hi %s') % (name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the confirmations in a tuple and check if `x` is in the tuple:

```
confirmations = ('yeah', 'yes', 'yea')
if x in confirmations:
    ...
```